# Convert a char to double

Tags: c

Ok, I have a `char` that is a number. How could I convert it into a `double`?

```
char c;
```

I've tried `(double)c`, but it converts to zero.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to convert the ascii code in `double`? Make your question more precise.

Comment: @Aleksandar: `atoi()` converts a string to an `int`; the OP wants a `double`. And it's not clear just what he's asking; see my answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

if you have a *null terminated* string that you wish to convert to double use `atof`:

```
const char *str = "3.14";
double x = atof(str);
printf("%f\n", x); //prints 3.140000
```

If you have a single character, casting should work:

```
char c = 'a'; //97 in ASCII
double x = (double)c; 
printf("%f\n", x); //prints 97.000000
```

If the character is zero then it print zeros of course:

```
char c = '\0';
double x = (double)c; 
printf("%f\n", x); //prints 0.000000
```

Note: `atof` and similar functions don't detect overflows and return zero on error, so there's no way to know if it failed (not sure if it sets `errno`), see also Keith's comments about *undefined behaviour* for certain values, so the point is you should use `strtol` for converting from strings to `int` and `strtod` for converting to `double` those have much better error handling:

```
const char *str = "3.14";
double x = strtod(str, NULL);
```

Comment: Note that "on success, the function returns the converted integral number as an int value".

Comment: @Maroun85 that's `atof` not `atoi`

Comment: is it `atof()` or it should be `atol()`

Comment: @Omkant `atol` is for integers `atof` for double, but really you shouldn't use either, check the update.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `atof()` has undefined behavior for some arguments, for example `atof(1.0e9999)` (assuming `double` can't represent that value).

Comment: @KeithThompson hence the note

Comment: @mux: Yes, but "undefined behavior" can be much more dangerous than "don't detect overflows".

Comment: @KeithThompson I've added that to the note, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

To answer the question you asked:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char c = 42;
    // double d = (double)c; The cast is not needed here, because ...
    double d = c;    // ... the conversion is done implicitly.
    printf("c = %d\n", c);
    printf("d = %f\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```

`char` is an integer type; its range is typically either `-128` to `+127` or `0` to `+255`. It's most commonly used to store character values like `'x'`, but it can also be used to store small integers.

But I suspect you really want to know how to convert a character *string*, like `"1234.5"`, to type `double` with the numeric value `1234.5`.  There are several ways to do this.

The `atof()` function takes a `char*` that points to a string, and returns a `double` value;  `atof("1234.5")` returns `1234.5`. But it does no real error handing; if the argument is too big, or isn't a number, it can behave badly. (I'm not sure of the details of that, but I believe its behavior is undefined in some cases.)

The `strtod()` function does the same thing and is much more robust, but it's more complex to use. Consult your system's documentation (`man strtod` if you're on a Unix-like system).

And as Coodey said in a comment, you need to make your question more precise. An example with actual code would have made it easier to figure out just what you're asking.